# PHP Prepared Statement to delete all records

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

How do you delete all contents of a table in PHP MySQL using prepared statement? Do I have to use prepared statement to be safe or does using `$deleteall = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM mytable;");` works with no difference?

Is this how it's supposed to be done:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable");
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no point in using prepared statements when you don't have parameters.

Prepared statements exist to make if efficient to execute a statement multiple times, possibly with different arguments. They also help with SQL injection prevention: you don't have to remember to apply quoting and escaping manually. But if you're going to run something only once there are no parameters, don't bother with prepared statements.

Comment: Is this true? Can anyone confirm this? I was hoping this is true as it confuses me that I had to use prepared statement to pull out records from the database where no user-specification is required but was told in the past that even if no user-input is being inserted into the query, I must still use prepared statement :s

Comment: It is true. But you have to define user-input as "Something that a been input by a user at some point in the past" - so when you are fetching a username from the database and then use that username in a where clause you have to use prepared statements again.

Comment: Also "They also apply correct quoting and escapes " doesn't directly work this way, the values are never put into the query but into an object tree when everything got parsed already... but it comes down to the conclusion that you don't have to care about those two things when using ps.

Comment: Yeah so something like `"SELECT username,userpassword FROM logintable WHERE useraccess = 'Level2'"` will not need to be a Prepared Statement since `'Level2'` isn't user-specified or not user input?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to delete records with criteria parameters so the best way to do it:

```php
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id=?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->bind_param("i", $memberId);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this way, it is working fine on me. Hope it will help you.

```
$stmt= 'DELETE from mytable';
$result = $conn->prepare($stmt);
$result->execute();
```